# APNS: CSR generated from Windows is invalid

Tags: apple-push-notifications, csr

I'm trying to enable push notifications in my app, the problem is that I can't generate the certificate because whenever I upload my CSR (generated from Windows) I get the following error:

> Invalid CSR Select a valid Certificate Signing Request.

The CSR was generated using the following specs:

- Key Size 2048 bit
- RSA Algorithm

I did the same process last year and I was able to generate the certificate but now all I get is the error above.. did Apple change anything about the CSR or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it........
The CSR first and last line were:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
.
.
.
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I had to remove the **NEW** word and it worked, I was able to generate the `.cer` file